# Trying to do multiple request simultaneously and then add to a set with Aiohttp and python

Tags: python, get, aiohttp

I have the below code that will do GET requests at an http endpoint. However, doing them one at a time is super slow. So the code below will do them 50 at a time, but I need to add them to a set (I figured a set would be fastest, because there will be duplicate objects returned with this script. Right now, this just returns the objects in a string 50 at a time, when I need them separated so I can sort them after they are all in a set. I'm new to python so I'm not sure what else to try

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession


async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.read()


async def run(r):
    url = "http://httpbin.org/get"
    tasks = []

    # Fetch all responses within one Client session,
    # keep connection alive for all requests.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(r):
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(url.format(i), session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        # you now have all response bodies in this variable
        print(responses)


def print_responses(result):
    print(result)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(20))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Right now, it just dumps all of the request responses to `result`, I need it to add each response to a set so I can work with the data later

Comment: If you return `set(responses)` then you can get what you want as the return of the `loop.run_until_complete(future)`